# After upgrading to firebase admin (8.19.0), --import of database doesnt allow database modification

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-tools

If I start firebase emulator with

```
firebase emulators:start --import <pathToMyDB>
```

After upgrade I'm not able to modify the db either with web interface or from the app (android app), it gets reset automatically to the stored exported files.

Answer (score 0):

I did a 'firebase init' in another folder and added my firebase functions, settings.. to it, it worked in the new folder. Not sure how it got screwed up in my previous folder, raised an issue with github firebase-tools also.